# How to set only one value of column as true and rest false

Tags: sql, sql-server, winforms, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have a column in my database called `PresentYear` which is used to set a particular year as the academic year for the school for ex. 2014-15. I've added a `default constraint` which sets all values to `'N'`. On `assigncurrentyear` button click I want to set it as `'Y'`and when I set another year as `PresentYear` the previously set `PresentYear` should be reset to `'N'` and only one row in the table should have `'Y'`. I'll be passing `academicID` to set `PresentYear` and I am using a `stored procedure` to do so and I'm stuck here .

How should the stored procedure be?

```
create PROCEDURE [dbo].[USP_SetAcademicYear]
    @AcademicID INT
AS
BEGIN
    IF(@AcademicID != 0)
    BEGIN 
        UPDATE dbo.Academic_Master 
        SET presentYear = 'y'
        WHERE AcademicId = @AcademicID
    END
END
```

Comment: I would suggest to create/use queries to get the correct result. Setting a column to something this transient requires too much work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just update both rows that need updating:

```
create PROCEDURE [dbo].[USP_SetAcademicYear]
    @AcademicID INT
AS
BEGIN
    IF(@AcademicID != 0)
    BEGIN 
        UPDATE dbo.Academic_Master 
        SET presentYear = CASE
             WHEN AcademicId = @AcademicID THEN 'y'
             ELSE 'N' END
        WHERE AcademicId = @AcademicID or presentYear = 'y'
    END
END
```

Comment: @saurabh64 Damien is right, you should use his answer because if the tables have too much rows, my answer will not be efficient. using Damien's code you only need to update 2 rows each button clicked.

Comment: Probably doesn't matter in this case but be aware that the other answer (which, if it works for you, you should accept by hitting the tick mark) will update *all* rows in the table. Doesn't matter for a few rows, but could be problematic if you're dealing with millions of rows in other tables in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Not Equal To](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176020.aspx) operator :

```
UPDATE Academic_Master
SET presentYear='N'
WHERE AcademicId <> @AcademicID
```

UPDATE :
so your stored procedure will look like this

```
create PROCEDURE [dbo].[USP_SetAcademicYear]
@AcademicID INT
AS
BEGIN
    IF(@AcademicID!=0)
    BEGIN 
        update Academic_Master 
        set presentYear='y'
        WHERE AcademicId=@AcademicID

        UPDATE Academic_Master
        SET presentYear='N'
        WHERE AcademicId <> @AcademicID
    END
END
```

Comment: I have a default constraint which sets all values to 'N' when a record is inserted in the DB

Comment: what do you mean with all values? do you set presentYear value of all records to 'N' when a record is added?

Comment: Yes,Only on button click I want to set it as 'Y'

Comment: Okay, so on button click you will run the stored procedure right? and after you set a row as presentYear, you want to set presentYear of all rows **except** the selected to 'N', am I right? your script already set the presentYear of selected row to 'Y', you can add my code to your script to set presentYear of all rows **except** the selected to 'N'.

Comment: You can't use `GO` in the middle of a stored procedure! `GO` is **NOT** a SQL statement or command - it's a SQL Server Management Studio feature